# how to add class and id in codemirror

Tags: codemirror

i would like to add an id along with the class that codemirror adds.

does anyone know where to start with this?

the outcome i want is something like

```
<span id="1234" class="cm-cm-overlay cm-url">google</span>
<span id="3452" class="cm-cm-overlay cm-url">microsoft</span>
```

i know how to add the cm-url class with a custom mode, but how to i add an id on each line?

as to why i want to do this, i am working on a project that I need to link each particular line with a database record, i thought the id could be the linking field.

any ideas on where to start?  i haven't found any documentation on it.

Comment: why do you need the dom for that? what about getting all lines with `cm.getValue().split('\n')`

Comment: you just want to add a unique id to each `cm-overlay`?